# NodeJs or Python libraries for estimating the gas costs

Tags: solidity, gas, hardhat, gas-estimate

I am looking for libraries in Python or NodeJs which can provide gas cost estimations like the one provided by Hardhat. Please share knowledge you have regarding this..